# Can it rain upsidedown?

Tags: density, liquid-state

Is it possible for it to rain upside down? I am guessing this would happen if the reason rain lighter than the atmosphere. Is there any combination of liquid and atmosphere which could cause it to rain upsidedown?

Comment: That would be evaporation.

Comment: @Lambda well now I feel foolish...

Comment: How about a strong force going upwards near a lake. Then the flow should be upwards? Like something extremely massive in the upper atmosphere :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can it rain upside-down?

Inside of clouds, yes. The very smallest water particles in a cloud are minimally effected by gravity. This is an extremely low Reynolds number domain. Drag is by far the dominant force on the very smallest water particles in a cloud. They go whichever way the wind blows.

The wind can blow up in thunderstorms, sometimes so very much upward that even larger rain particles get caught in the updraft. Those rain particles freeze if that updraft carries rain particles above the freezing line. The growing hailstone can hover near the top of the cloud for some time before it gets so massive that it falls to Earth.